# Repeated crash errors following El Capitan Upgrade

Tags: mac, imac, crash, macos

I upgraded to El Capitan and I keep getting repeated crash errors for the following:

```
Process:               com.apple.geod [803]
Path: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/ com.apple.geod.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.geod
Identifier:            com.apple.geod


Process:               com.apple.BKAgentService [892]
Path:                  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BookKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com. apple.BKAgentService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.BKAgentService
Identifier:            com.apple.BKAgentService



Process:               DataDetectorsDynamicData [1286]
Path:                  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/Versions/A/XPCSer vices/DataDetectorsDynamicData.xpc/Contents/MacOS/DataDetectorsDynamicData
Identifier:            DataDetectorsDynamicData
Version:               7.0 (460)



Process:               LaterAgent [767]
Path:                  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/La terAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/LaterAgent
Identifier:            LaterAgent
Version:               ???
```

It also says the below text for all of the applications.

```
Application Specific Information:
Sandbox creation failed: Container object initialization failed.
NSCocoaErrorDomain:516
```

What is causing these errors? I click ok and they keep popping up 5 seconds later consistently. I have tried repairing permissions, Clearing cache, running maintenance scripts. I can post the entire crash log if needed.